# How to find files and skip directories in os.listdir

Tags: python, file-manager

I use `os.listdir` and it works fine, but I get sub-directories in the list also, which is not what I want: I need only files.

What function do I need to use for that?

I looked also at `os.walk` and it seems to be what I want, but I'm not sure of how it works.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need to filter out directories; `os.listdir()` lists all *names* in a given path. You can use [`os.path.isdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) for this:

```
basepath = '/path/to/directory'
for fname in os.listdir(basepath):
    path = os.path.join(basepath, fname)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        # skip directories
        continue
```

Note that this only *filters out directories* after following symlinks. `fname` is not necessarily a *regular file*, it could also be a symlink to a file. If you need to filter out symlinks as well, you'd need to use [`not os.path.islink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.islink) first.

On a modern Python version (3.5 or newer), an even better option is to use the [`os.scandir()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir); this produces [`DirEntry()` instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry). In the common case, this is faster as the direntry loaded already has cached enough information to determine if an entry is a directory or not:

```py
basepath = '/path/to/directory'
for entry in os.scandir(basepath):
    if entry.is_dir():
        # skip directories
        continue
    # use entry.path to get the full path of this entry, or use
    # entry.name for the base filename
```

You can use `entry.is_file(follow_symlinks=False)` if only regular files (and not symlinks) are needed.

`os.walk()` does the same work under the hood; unless you need to recurse down subdirectories, you don't need to use `os.walk()` here.

Comment: minor correction as this raises an error "AttributeError: 'posix.DirEntry' object has no attribute 'isdir'" - `is_dir` is the correct method name.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a nice little one-liner in the form of a list comprehension:

```
[f for f in os.listdir(your_directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(your_directory, f))]
```

This will `return` a `list` of filenames within the specified `your_directory`.

Comment: Alternative: `filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(your_directory))`

Comment: This doesn't actually work, as `f` is a filename, not a full path. You'd need `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(your_directory, f))` there.

Comment: i liked this better, and I also wanted to limit it to an extension so was able to add another condition at the end: ` and f.endswith('.txt')` .

Answer (score 8):

```
import os
directoryOfChoice = "C:\\" # Replace with a directory of choice!!!
filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(directoryOfChoice))
```

P.S: **os.getcwd()** returns the current directory.

Answer (score 7):

```
for fname in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isdir(fname):
       pass  # do your stuff here for directory
    else:
       pass  # do your stuff here for regular file
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution with os.walk() would be:

```
for r, d, f in os.walk('path/to/dir'):
    for files in f:
       # This will list all files given in a particular directory
```

Comment: What isn't obvious if you just copy/paste this is that it will loop over all directories _in all subdirectories_ of the starting directory.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an older post, let me please  add the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library introduced in 3.4 which provides an OOP style of handling directories and files for sakes of completeness. To get all files in a directory, you can use

```
def get_list_of_files_in_dir(directory: str, file_types: str ='*') -> list:
    return [f for f in Path(directory).glob(file_types) if f.is_file()]
```

Following your example, you could use it like this:

```
mypath = '/path/to/directory'
files = get_list_of_files_in_dir(mypath)
```

If you only want a subset of files depending on the file extension (e.g. "only csv files"), you can use:

```
files = get_list_of_files_in_dir(mypath, '*.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Note PEP 471 DirEntry object attributes is: is_dir(*, follow_symlinks=True)

so...

```
from os import scandir
folder = '/home/myfolder/'
for entry in scandir(folder):
    if entry.is_dir():
        # do code or skip
        continue
    myfile = folder + entry.name
    #do something with myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one liner python code you can use this for code readability and beautification

Just add comments in the line before the code what you are doing with it, so it is easier to deal with while debugging.

> ## Listing all files in the dir filtering the folders

```
list_of_files = [file for file in os.listdir(basepath) if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(basepath, file))]
```