# List only files but not directories using list.files

Tags: regex, r, directory

How can I list only files, but not directories using `list.files` (not recursively)?  It has an `include.dirs` argument, but this is ignored when not being used recursively.

I had been thinking something like

```
list.files(path=myDir, pattern="[^/]$")
```

but that doesn't seem to work, or a few variations on it.  Is there a regex that I can plug in here or a function.  I know I can do `list.dirs` and take a `setdiff`, but this is already slow enough, I want this to be quicker.

PS: currently on linux, but need something that works cross-platform.

PPS: `file.info` is really slow, so I think that is also not going to work.

PPPS: It doesn't need to be `list.files`, that is just the function I had thought should do it.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything much faster than `f <- function() {setdiff(list.files(), list.dirs(full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE))}; f()`.

Comment: do all the files have an extension? `list.files('~/desktop', full.names = TRUE, pattern = '\\.\\w+$')`

Comment: What about a `system("ls <args>")` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this regex pattern that matches any file containing letters or numbers and contains the dot extension (to leave out subdirectories but unfortunately files without extensions):

```
# WITH ANCHORING
files <- list.files(path, pattern=("[a-zA-Z0-9]*[.][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"))

# MATCHING LETTER AND/OR NUMBER FILES WITH EXTENSION
files = list.files(myDir, pattern=("[a-zA-Z0-9]*[.]"))

# WILDCARD FILE MATCHING WITH EXTENSION
files = list.files(myDir, pattern=("*[.]"))
```

Some other regex variations to catch files with periods (note these also get directories with periods and miss files with no extensions)

```
list.files(pattern="\\..+$")
list.files(pattern="\\.[[:alnum:]]+$")
```

And using `system2` with `ls` seems to work pretty well (thanks @42- as well from comments),

```
system2("ls", args=c("-al", "|", "grep", "^-"))
```

should get only regular files (including ones without extensions), or

```
system2("ls", args=c("--classify"))
```

should return files with directories having a "/" appended so they can be determined.

For an alternative open-source solution, consider the [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207936/python-how-to-find-files-and-skip-directories-in-os-listdir) solution that allows you to condition if item is a directory and using `os.path.join()` is agnostic to any OS platform.

```
import os

files = [f for f in os.listdir(myDir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(myDir, f))]
```